# Getting error with Spring MV 4.0 Restful webservice when I am trying RequestMethod.POST

Tags: json, web-services, rest, spring-mvc

I am using Postman console to hit service(http://localhost:8080/MyResful/countries1) and it working fine with GET method and giving the following response

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "countryName": "India",
    "population": 10000
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "countryName": "Pakistan",
    "population": 7000
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "countryName": "Nepal",
    "population": 8000
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "countryName": "China",
    "population": 20000
  }
]
```

But it is not working with (http://localhost:8080/MyResful/countries1)POST method and giving the error:

HTTP Status 415, requestThe server refused this request because questing entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method ().

In Postman I  set header Accept and Content-type "application/JSON"

Please help me on this issue.

I am working with Spring MVC using JSON objects
Here is my controller class:

```
package com.ness.myrestful.controller;

import java.util.List;  
import com.ness.myrestful.bean.Desh;  
import com.ness.myrestful.service.DeshService; 
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;  

@RestController  
public class CrudRestController {  

    DeshService countryService = new DeshService();  

 @RequestMapping(value = "/countries1", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")  
 public List<Desh> getCountries() {  
  List<Desh> listOfCountries = countryService.getAllCountries();  
  return listOfCountries;  
 }  

 @RequestMapping(value = "/country1/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")  
 public Desh getCountryById(@PathVariable int id) {  
  return countryService.getCountry(id);  
 }  

 @RequestMapping(value = "/countries1", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")  
 public Desh addCountry(@RequestBody Desh country) {  
  return countryService.addCountry(country);  
 }  

 @RequestMapping(value = "/countries1", method = RequestMethod.PUT, headers = "Accept=application/json")
 public Desh updateCountry(@RequestBody Desh country) {  
  return countryService.updateCountry(country);  

 }  

 @RequestMapping(value = "/country1/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, headers = "Accept=application/json")  
 public void deleteCountry(@PathVariable("id") int id) {  
  countryService.deleteCountry(id);  

 }   
}  

********************
```

I am working with Spring MVC using JSON objects

Here is Bean class

```
package com.ness.myrestful.bean;


public class Desh {

    int id;  
     String countryName;   
     long population;  

     public Desh() {  
      super();  
     }  
     public Desh(int i, String countryName,long population) {  
      super();  
      this.id = i;  
      this.countryName = countryName;  
      this.population=population;  
     }  
     public int getId() {  
      return id;  
     }  
     public void setId(int id) {  
      this.id = id;  
     }  
     public String getCountryName() {  
      return countryName;  
     }  
     public void setCountryName(String countryName) {  
      this.countryName = countryName;  
     }  
     public long getPopulation() {  
      return population;  
     }  
     public void setPopulation(long population) {  
      this.population = population;  
     }   

}

********************************
```

I am working with Spring MVC using JSON objects
    Here is my service class

```
package com.ness.myrestful.service;

    import java.util.ArrayList;  
    import java.util.HashMap;  
    import java.util.List;    
    import com.ness.myrestful.bean.Desh;  

    public class DeshService {  

     static HashMap<Integer,Desh> countryIdMap=getCountryIdMap();  


     public DeshService() {  
      super();  

      if(countryIdMap==null)  
      {  
       countryIdMap=new HashMap<Integer,Desh>();  
      // Creating some objects of Country while initializing  
       Desh indiaCountry=new Desh(1, "India",10000);  
       Desh chinaCountry=new Desh(4, "China",20000);  
       Desh nepalCountry=new Desh(3, "Nepal",8000);  
       Desh bhutanCountry=new Desh(2, "Pakistan",7000);  


       countryIdMap.put(1,indiaCountry);  
       countryIdMap.put(4,chinaCountry);  
       countryIdMap.put(3,nepalCountry);  
       countryIdMap.put(2,bhutanCountry);  
      }  
     }  

     public List<Desh> getAllCountries()  
     {  
      List<Desh> countries = new ArrayList<Desh>(countryIdMap.values());  
      return countries;  
     }  

     public Desh getCountry(int id)  
     {  
         Desh country= countryIdMap.get(id);  
      return country;  
     }  
     public Desh addCountry(Desh country)  
     {  
      country.setId(getMaxId()+1);  
      countryIdMap.put(country.getId(), country);  
      return country;  
     }  

     public Desh updateCountry(Desh country)  
     {  
      if(country.getId()<=0)  
       return null;  
      countryIdMap.put(country.getId(), country);  
      return country;  

     }  
     public void deleteCountry(int id)  
     {  
      countryIdMap.remove(id);  
     }  

     public static HashMap<Integer, Desh> getCountryIdMap() {  
      return countryIdMap;  
     }  

     // Utility method to get max id  
     public static int getMaxId()  
     {   int max=0;  
     for (int id:countryIdMap.keySet()) {    
      if(max<=id)  
       max=id;  

     }    
     return max;  
     } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove header and try consumes.

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/countries1", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)  
     public Desh addCountry(@RequestBody Desh country) {  
      return countryService.addCountry(country);  
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Proper approach to fix your issue would be a global configuration as you mentioned that you are developing a `json` based application.

Please add following in you configuration xml file,

```
<!-- Configure to plugin JSON as request and response in method handler -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <beans:property name="messageConverters">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
    <beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
    </beans:bean>
```

This will make sure that your JSON request object is converted `to` and `from` during server-client communication.

You can then remove the headers from your handler methods in `controller`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/countries1", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")  
 public Desh addCountry(@RequestBody Desh country) {  
  return countryService.addCountry(country);  
 }
```

To,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/countries1", method = RequestMethod.POST)  
 public Desh addCountry(@RequestBody Desh country) {  
  return countryService.addCountry(country);  
 }
```

Also make sure that you have properly add `jackson` jars in your dependencies as well.